# Export data from Firebase Crashlytics console?

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, firebase-console

I'm trialling Firebase Crashlytics and the console display of log data is messed up (see image below.) Is there any way to export the full crash report? I can't see one in the Firebase console - I never used the original Crashlytics but I see that it has an export facility.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a way to export crashes with the beta version of Crashlytics in Firebase. It's something we're thinking about though. What platform and browser is that screenshot on? Would love to get that fixed up.

Comment: Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) on MacOs 10.12.6. PM me if you need to look at the specific report. Oh, wait, no PM on SO.

Comment: Thanks. I've let the team know about the formatting issue so we can get it fixed. I'll let you know if we have other questions!

Comment: @Clyde are you able to write into Firebase support and let us know the project and app this log formatting is happening with? We haven't been able to reproduce it on our end.

Comment: It used to be possible to export from Fabrics Crashlyitcs [via service hook](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/service-hooks.html). Any updates on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, how about now?  It's 2020.  Can we export crash data through an API now?

Comment: There's an integration between Crashlytics and BigQuery that give you the ability export your data: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/bigquery-export

Comment: in this case, is the usage of BigQuery (in GCP) has unlimited storage volume or charged beyond a limit ?

Comment: Is there any way to do this without BigQuery?

Comment: Same question as above. Would be nice if we could download a CSV of the issues and the stats for each.

Comment: Update: I saw that BigQuery can export to CSV, so I linked BigQuery and attempted to to do so, but after struggling with the queries and eventually getting it to show the data in a strange nested format, I tried to export and got an error saying that it can't export a dataset with nested columns/fields.

Comment: Any more updates? I had all I needed with Fabric - just a simple csv download of crashes.

Comment: Hi! Any updates about this? Do we have now a way to export a CSV with the Crashlytics data?

Comment: Why did you decide to buy Fabric and remove all useful features from it?

Comment: @Alexizamerican Just add one simple button on each crash to allow exporting that particular crash in to a txt file. That alone would be really useful and it is literally 5 minutes worth of work for a junior developer.

Answer (score -2):

not from firebase crashlytics but you can do that via google play console by saving reports and then exporting as csv