# How to export data from Firebase Crashlytics to another application?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery, crashlytics

I am interested in fetching the Crash-free users statistics and the user affected by Crashes trend from the Google firebase Crashlytics.

Is there any API using which I can call using my application to export the data from Firebase Crashlytics?

I looked at a few other similar questions like theses:

- [How long does Firebase store my crash data? / Export data from Crashlytics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51572955/how-long-does-firebase-store-my-crash-data-export-data-from-crashlytics)
- [Export data from Firebase Crashlytics console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662713/export-data-from-firebase-crashlytics-console)
- [How to export crash-free users from firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57286697/how-to-export-crash-free-users-from-firebase)

, but none of them actually mention a solution to export data out of Crashlytics.

As suggested in one of the questions above, I could export the data into Big Query and then calculate the crash-free statistic myself, but I haven't used Big Query before and I'm not sure if I will be able to export that data from Big Query either?

Is it possible to get that data out of Crashlytics somehow?

**UPDATE**

Upon looking a bit more closely at the networking console in Google Chrome, while loading the Crashlytics data for my App, I can see that Crashlytics makes a POST call to the following endpoint (along with its auth/cookies):

```
https://***.google.com/v1/projects/***/clients/ios:abc.def.MyApp:getDailyRealtimeCrashUsersReport?alt=json&key=xyz
```

and the response to this contains the exact data that I am looking for:

```
{
  "report": {
    "dailyUsers": [
      {
        "dateMs": "xxxx",
        "totalUsers": 1234,
        "crashUsers": 12
      }
      ...
      ...
    ],
    "totalUsers": 12345,
    "totalCrashUsers": 123
  }
}
```

Is there a way I could directly call this API along with a proper auth (OAuth2 maybe?) through my (Java) code, and skip having to go to BigQuery and do all those extra steps? It would be easier to make a direct call to this endpoint and get the data directly instead of first exporting it to BigQuery and the running a custom query (/queries?) there and the exporting the data through another API.

And,

If such a solution is not possible, then is there a way to get a similar kind of data from BigQuery and export similarly in JSON it via a BigQuery API call?

from the BigQuery API link given in the answer below, I can see some APIs which support exporting models/projects/jobs/datasets/tables etc.. but couldn't figure out if there is a way to export data based on a custom queries that I would need to run to get the data I want?

Comment: Exporting to BigQuery is a very reasonable option, @rmesteves answer provides the exporting-how-to link. Once the data is in Bigquery, there are several options to make use of it: (1) Export to a Google Cloud Storage bucket and download it from there. (2) Visualise the data in Google Data Studio. (3) Use [Crisp BigQuery](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react) (I'm the author) to build a website hydrated by BigQuery data and exercise complete control over data presentation and costs. (4) Use Google connector for Google Sheets or Google connector for Excel to export data. (5) Use Google SDK.

Comment: hm, BigQuery seems like a possible solution, but it would export a lot of extra data, which I don't really need.. and I'm not really sure on how to get the data in the format that I require from the BigQuery API, or even if it is possible to get tat kind of response from the API for that matter.. ?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `Crashlytics` doesn't support this kind of API you're searching for.

About exporting from `Crashlytics` to `BigQuery`, I've found the following information [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/bigquery-export)

**Enabling BigQuery export**

> 1. Go to the Integrations page in the Firebase console.
> 2. In the BigQuery card, click Link.
> 3. Follow the on-screen instructions to enable BigQuery.

**When you link your project to BiqQuery:**

> - Firebase exports a copy of your existing data to BigQuery.
> - Firebase sets up daily syncs of your data from your Firebase project to BigQuery.
> - By default, all apps in your project are linked to BigQuery and any apps that you later add to the project are automatically linked to
>     BigQuery.

**What data is exported to BigQuery?**

> Firebase Crashlytics data is exported into a `BigQuery` dataset named
>   firebase_crashlytics. By default, individual tables will be created
>   inside the `Crashlytics` data set for each app in your project.
>   `Firebase` names the tables based on the app's bundle identifier, with
>   periods converted to underscores, and a platform name appended to the
>   end. For example, data for an app with the ID com.google.test would be
>   in a table named com_google_test_ANDROID.

To export data from `BigQuery`, you can use the [BigQuery API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/) or use the [BigQuery SDK](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) for some programming language.

Does it help you? If it doesn't, please provide me more information so I can provide you a better answer.

Comment: May I know, is there are any other options export Crashlytics data other than the BigQuiry table?  My requirement is export Crashlytics data to Azure

Answer (score 3):

The [Google Analytics Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1) is a solution to export crashAffectedUsers & crashFreeUsersRate data from Crashlytics. crashAffectedUsers is number of users that logged a crash, and crashFreeUsersRate number of users without crash events divided by the total number of users. The [Data API schema page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema) contains more details about these metrics.

An example request to the [RunReport](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runReport) method looks like the following:

```
{
  "dateRanges": [
    {
      "startDate": "7daysAgo",
      "endDate": "today"
    }
  ],
  "dimensions": [
    {
      "name": "date"
    }
  ],
  "metrics": [
    {
      "name": "crashFreeUsersRate"
    },
    {
      "name": "crashAffectedUsers"
    },
    {
      "name": "totalUsers"
    }
  ]
}
```

An example response row looks like the following. This row means: on 2021-11-13, the crash free users rate was 99.836%, 2 users were affected by crashes, and 1220 total users used your app.

```
    {
      "dimensionValues": [
        {
          "value": "20211113"
        }
      ],
      "metricValues": [
        {
          "value": "0.99836"
        },
        {
          "value": "2"
        },
        {
          "value": "1220"
        }
      ]
    },
```